# Div is much wider than it should be

Tags: css, responsive-design, resize

I'm trying to make my site a little more mobile-friendly. I have some graphs that look best when they can be pretty wide (800px), but I would prefer for them to shrink on mobile instead of having a scroll bar. I've added this to a stylesheet:

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
    div.graph {
        max-width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        height:400px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:601px){
    div.graph{
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: auto;
        height: 400px;
    }
}
```

And included that in my master page:

```
<link href="~/Styles/ResponsiveDesign.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Here is one of the divs that holds a graph:

```
<div class="graph" id="myDiv" ></div>
```

The problem is when I view the page with the browser full-size now, the graph is huge--far more than 800 px. Even if I change the max-width to something ridiculous like 25px, it's still huge. Any thoughts?

Comment: For future users to know, it would be great if you could accept an answer, if any, that solve your question, or let us know what is missing, so we can find one that does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this (and make sure custom CSS is loaded last if you use a library)

*Update based on a comment*

*Since inline style work, add `!important` like this and it should work*

*`width: 800px !important;`*
*`max-width: 100% !important;`*

*and if it does work, you do have another rule overriding these or else they would have worked without the `!important`*

```css
div.graph{
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 150px;
  background: red
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px){
    div.graph {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="graph" id="myDiv" ></div>
```

In this particular case you actually don't need the media query at all

```css
div.graph{
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 150px;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="graph" id="myDiv" ></div>
```

Comment: For some reason it's still not working--I'm even setting the width to 200px and it's still going across the entire screen.

Comment: @issharp This code work, as shown in above snippet, which should tell you that it gets overridden else where in your own CSS. Make sure custom CSS is loaded last.

Comment: @issharp Updated my answer

Comment: @issharp Did my update help?, and if not, what can I do more?

Comment: It turned out that I was doing something wrong with linking to my stylesheet, so it was being overridden by another one. So, the problem was somewhere else in my code, but your answers were most helpful, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i think you should set it in percentage.

Comment: I don't really want to--I want it to be 800px if the screen is wide enough, and to smaller if the screen isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if I understand it correctly you are trying to set the max width to 800px if the screen's width is bigger than 600px. How bout concretely setting the width of the div to 800px if the screen is bigger than 800px?

Alright, than the only other thing I can think of is its calling the other css block where you set the max-width to 100%. Maybe since its the same class name it is doing this I dont know. You could try commenting out that line and just trying it to see what happens. And sorry Im editing and not commenting I just started so I cant comment...?

Comment: Aah, sorry, I should've said that I've tried that. I realize the above code is kind of pointless since I'm essentially doing the same thing for all screens less than 800px, but I'm going to add other things that are different depending on screen size. Anyway, yeah, even when I change it to how you said, it's still much larger.

Comment: I messed around with my own stuff and if you create the div like this              <div class="mydiv" style="max-width: 100%"> it doesnt stretch it

Comment: That does work. I'd rather have it be in external CSS if that was possible (which I know it should be), but unfortunately every time I take out what you just mentioned, it goes back to full-size (even when I link to the external CSS at the very bottom of the head element, so nothing else should be overriding it).

Comment: Ok here I maybe got an idea. Is it possible to make 2 different divs with different class names and depending on the screen size setting either to visible or hide. Cause the only thing I can think of is the two different css blocks conflicting because of the class name

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be with the graph size itself, could you inspect element and check the size of the contents of the graph? My guess is that the div is the correct size, the graph isn't. We'd need to know how you are creating the graph for more specifics. Could you screen or put a demo of the graph?

Possibly also try a more specific selector? Ex:

```
body div#id div.graph{}
```

(I can't comment, sorry if this is not an answer)